# How to block access to web-hosting servers?

Tags: web-hosting, blacklist, block

Is there a way to block all web-hosting servers trying to access my server? There are a lot of hacked websites used to do damage to my server and only common thing is IP of agressor (many of IP's) is always identyfied as Hosting Provider on websites like IPHub.info website. As far as I know there is no detection method to identify an web-hosting other than having a blacklist of all o them. Am I wrong?

Comment: The usual solution to this problem on Linux systems is to install fail2ban. if you use search in the top right I'm sure you'll find lots of information to help you.

Comment: Fail2ban is in use already.

Comment: Then all you need to do is configure it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the geolocation database from ip2location.com to identify if the IP address is belongs to a data center.

Check out their PX2 database which can lookup a IP if belongs to Data Center (DCH), and block it in your backend codes.

You can refer the sample codes in their website at https://www.ip2location.com/ip2proxy/developers

Answer (score 0):

Access control is an important part of managing visitor access to your website. Visitors can be restricted from accessing your site by using the IP deny manager in your cPanel or by adding the Allow or Deny code in your .htaccess file.

This is especially useful when robots or malicious visitors from specific countries or domain addresses spam your site or place comments on your site that you do not want. The following sections will explain how to block IP's in your .htaccess file and through the cPanel IP deny manager.

Access control by IP address
The Allow and Deny directives let you allow and deny access based on the IP address or host name of the originating visitors server. The syntax is as follows:

1. Allows IP 122.102.1.2 access to your [website](https://www.bestnetreview.com/).
   Allow from 122.102.1.2
2. Denys IP 25.122.6.3 access to your website.
   Deny from 25.122.6.3